# How to wrap C++ class method having a parameter or returning an instance of another C++ class in C?

Tags: c++, c, wrapper

I have a C++ class `A` having methods while some of them using an instance of another C++ class `B` as parameter and some are returning an instance of another C++ class `C`. How to correctly wrap in C language the class `A` and all of its methods?

I don't think that my question is a duplicate, since all the existing examples are showing C wrapper (header and source) for a simple C++ class with methods having parameters or return values of simple data type, like `int`, `char*`, etc.

```
class A {
  public:
    A(int param1);
    int getValue();
  private:
    int value;
}

// method B::DoSomething() has a parameter of type (class) "A"
class B {
  public:
    void DoSomething(A param1);
}

// method C::SetSomething() returns an instance of class "A"
class C {
  public:
    A SetSomething(int value);
}
```

I know how to write C-language wrapper for class `A` and its method: using the `extern "C" { ... }` construct.

But how to do it for classes `B` and `C` and their methods?

Comment: How would the C API expose `A` in the first place?

Comment: If you have `A`, `B` and `C` as structs and then have some function like `void B_DoSomething(struct A *param1)` and `struct A C_SetSomething(int value)`. Is this what you want?

Comment: The C language doesn't have accessibility in its structures (e.g. `public` or `private`).  Also, if you want functions inside C structures, you'll have to use function pointers.

Comment: It's doable because there are compilers that convert from C++ to C. They use the object as parameter, for example object.DoSomething(param) becomes  DoSomething(object, param);, each method is renamed according to its signature (the type of its arguments and return value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic way is to create a wrapper for each C++ class and a method to generate pointers to those wrappers and another to delete them.

```
extern "C" {

struct WA{
    void* self;
};

struct WA* new_A( int p1 ){
    WA* wa = new WA;
    wa->self = new A( p1 );
    return wa; 
}

void delete_A( WA* wa ){
    delete static_cast<A*>( wa->self );
    delete wa;
}

}
```

Then you transform each method of each class into a function taking a pointer the struct as the first argument. `A::getValue` becomes

```
int A_getValue( WA* wa) {
    return static_cast<A*>( wa->self )->getValue();
}
```

Instances can be passed in via pointer, so `B::DoSomething` becomes

```
void B_DoSomething( WB *wb, WA *param1){
    static_cast<B*>( wb->self )->DoSomething( *static_cast<A*>( param1->self ) );
}
```

Likewise you can return instances by pointer. `C::SetSomething` then becomes

```
struct WA* C_SetSomething( WC* wc, int value ){
    A a = static_cast<C*>( wc->self )->SetSomething( value );
    return new_A( a.getValue() );
}
```

You will need to be very careful with your memory management in the C code. See working example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07a6cb797c596530).

Comment: Thank you @Thomas ! This is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest converting `struct B` and `struct C` into functions, since they have no members:

```
void B_DoSomething(A * p_param)
{
  //...
}

A C_SetSomething(int value)
{
  A variable;
  variable.value = value;
  return variable;
}
```

As a reminder, you should prefer to pass structures by pointer in the C language.  Otherwise the compiler will generate copies (except when the compiler can optimize).

Answer (score 0):

In almost all cases, you *cannot*.

Only if the `struct` is a POD, which means that it is a trivial & standard-layout type and that has no non-static members that are non-POD themselves.

This means, basically, that you can only use structs that are blobs of data without extra behavior and that C "understands" equally as C++.

The reason is simple: C has no idea of C++ semantics. For instance, if your class has a destructor, who is going to run it? Or, if your class runs some code when copied, how can C know about it?

You have two options:

- Share only those types. If you are unsure whether something is a POD or not, assert it (in C++):

  ```
  static_assert(std::is_pod_v<T>);
  ```
- Keep your classes, but pass opaque pointers to C. Since you are passing just pointers, C won't do anything with them.

Note that your example classes `B` and `C` are *not* PODs, so you cannot do it for those.